# linear algebra: invertible matrices and subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

is $ inv= [A \in Mat(n;F):A$ is invertible $]$ a subspace of $mat (n;F)$

and

is $ Noninv= [A \in Mat(n;F):A$ is not invertible $]$ a subspace of $mat (n;F)$

not sure how to get started on this.

Comment: please try to write what ever you have tried....

Comment: nothing because i dont feel like have anywhere to go.

Comment: can you give example of one invertible matrix...

Comment: What do the square brackets mean? What does $Mat(n;F)$ mean?

Comment: NO and NO... $I-I=0$ ($I$ is the identity) and $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=I$.

Comment: Ok, let us not complicate this... If $A$ is invertible, Do you see $-A$ is invertible???

Comment: Have you ever seen a proof that anything is a subspace of anything else? How was it done? Probably by using the definition of a subspace. That would be a good place to start.

Comment: @bubba has it right --- the place to start is with the definition of a subspace. Do you know what a subspace is? If not, *that's* where to start --- learn the definition! If you do know, then see whether those sets fit the definition. If you get stuck, come back and ask --- but let us know exactly what you have tried, and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\;\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}\!\!-1&1\\0&\!\!-1\end{pmatrix}\\{}\\{}\\
\bullet&\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\;\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\end{align*}$$